# Borders are not lined up

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm making navigation, where each div has a border, I have two rows, each section has 1/4 width but the borders are 1px off on each side.

screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/werxlj

```
  <div class="hidden md:block text-center">velke</div>
  <div class="flex-1 text-center borCenter">Jozko</div>
  <div class="flex-none text-center bor md:w-1/4">Ferko</div>


  <div class="hidden md:flex ">
    <div class="w-1/4 text-center borRight">Shop</div>
    <div class="w-1/4 text-center ">Jurnal</div>
    <div class="w-1/4 text-center ">About us</div>
    <div class="w-1/4 text-center borLeft">Contact</div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
<style scoped>
.bor {
  border: 2px solid rgb(17, 24, 39);
}
.borLeft {
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(17, 24, 39);
}
.borRight {
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(17, 24, 39);
}
.borTopNone {
  border: 2px solid rgb(17, 24, 39);
  border-top: none;
}
.borCenter {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(17, 24, 39);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(17, 24, 39);
}
</style>
```

desired effect:
https://prnt.sc/wes5j8

I have a feeling that there is more proper way of doing it, I appreciate any help!

thanks

Comment: Can you share the css as with out this it will be hard to answer.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention I'm useing tailwind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the percentage for width and useing flex: 1 and flex: 2

instead